# jasmine test for window.bind() in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive which has the below which i need to test in jasmine.

```
        angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
            scrollFunc(element);
        });
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
            resizeFunc(element);
        });
```

Both scrollFunc & resizeFunc are separate methods in the same directive. How do i test this block of code. Do i mock with $window or is there any other way. any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

force the scroll and the resize inside your jasmine test like this:

```
$(windowMock).scroll();
```